# How can I consistently convert strings like "3.71B" and "4M" to numbers in Python?

Tags: python, regex, finance, yahoo-finance

I have some rather mangled code that almost produces the **tangible price/book** from Yahoo Finance for companies (a nice module called `ystockquote` gets the **intangible price/book** value already).

My problem is this:

For one of the variables in the calculation, **shares outstanding** I'm getting strings like **10.89B** and **4.9M**, where **B** and **M** stand respectively for **billion** and **million**. I'm having trouble converting them to numbers, here's where I'm at:

```
shares=''.join(node.findAll(text=True)).strip().replace('M','000000').replace('B','000000000').replace('.','') for node in soup2.findAll('td')[110:112]
```

Which is pretty messy, but I think it would work if instead of

```
.replace('M','000000').replace('B','000000000').replace('.','')
```

I was using a regular expression with variables. I guess the question is simply which regular expression and variables. Other suggestions are also good.

#### EDIT:

To be specific I'm hoping to have something that works for numbers with zero, one, or two decimals but these answers all look helpful.

Comment: unrelated to your question, beware `join.strip.replace.replace.replace` constructs, they are hard to read and harder to debug. See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ and http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ and keep to them wholly. Your future self will thank you.

Comment: Unrelated to what was unrelated: I especially like `import this`

Comment: See also `import antigravity`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> d = {
        'K': 3,
        'M': 6,
        'B': 9
}
>>> def text_to_num(text):
        if text[-1] in d:
            num, magnitude = text[:-1], text[-1]
            return Decimal(num) * 10 ** d[magnitude]
        else:
            return Decimal(text)

>>> text_to_num('3.17B')
Decimal('3170000000.00')
>>> text_to_num('4M')
Decimal('4000000')
>>> text_to_num('4.1234567891234B')
Decimal('4123456789.1234000000000')
```

You can `int()` the result if you want too

Comment: `>>>text_to_num('4.1234567891234B') # 4123456789L`. tsk tsk. precision :)

Comment: I assume he is only having integer inputs anyway so that is not a problem and this solution still stands correct

Comment: it stands 'correct' until someone passes a sub-decimal-resolving input. Maybe you should throw an exception to reinforce this assumption.

Comment: Hahah, code battles! You guys are awesome, they're not only integers but either of your solutions would suffice because it doesn't need to be _that_ specific. There are only two decimals in each case though, so really @jamylak wins the code battle here in truth, as far as I can see. Unfortunatly I'm getting `inf` with both of your guys' solutions, but I think it's my fault because @jamylak has demonstrated that everyone's code works fine ;) I'm selecting his answer, partly for his enthusiasm and partly for my upper commentary (max two decimals) though the int assumption is not correct. Thanks!

Comment: The issues referred to by @PreetKukreti relate to an original revision of this code that converted to `int` which is why it was having issues, but that was shortly switched to `Decimal` completely so it has had no such issue since then

Answer (score 4):

Parse the numbers as floats, and use a multiplier mapping:

```
multipliers = dict(M=10**6, B=10**9)
def sharesNumber(nodeText):
    nodeText = nodeText.strip()
    mult = 1
    if nodeText[-1] in multipliers:
        mult = multipliers[nodeText[-1]]
        nodeText = nodeText[:-1]
    return float(nodeText) * mult
```

Comment: I think either of these will work but the bottom one seems like it might be easier so I'm trying it first.

Comment: `>>> sharesNumber('4.123456789B')
4123456788.9999995`
`>>> sharesNumber('123456789.987654321B')
1.2345678998765434e+17`

Comment: @jamylak: I doubt the share numbers will ever be that large.

Answer (score 3):

```
num_replace = {
    'B' : 1000000000,
    'M' : 1000000,
}

a = "4.9M" 
b = "10.89B" 

def pure_number(s):
    mult = 1.0
    while s[-1] in num_replace:
        mult *= num_replace[s[-1]]
        s = s[:-1]
    return float(s) * mult 

pure_number(a) # 4900000.0
pure_number(b) # 10890000000.0
```

This will work with idiocy like:

```
pure_number("5.2MB") # 5200000000000000.0
```

and because of the dictionary approach, you can add as many suffixes as you want in an easy to maintain way, and you can make it more lenient by expressing your dict keys in one capitalisation form and then doing a `.lower()` or `.upper()` to make it match.

Comment: `>>> pure_number('4.123456789B')
4123456788.9999995` also `>>> pure_number('123456789.987654321B')
1.2345678998765434e+17`

Comment: @jamylak this is a representation inaccuracy. Even python int or long have precision limitations given a few more digits. There is nothing wrong with the solution

Answer (score 2):

```
num_replace = {
    'B' : 'e9',
    'M' : 'e6',
}

def str_to_num(s):
    if s[-1] in num_replace:
        s = s[:-1]+num_replace[s[-1]]
    return int(float(s))
```

---

```
>>> str_to_num('3.71B')
3710000000L
>>> str_to_num('4M')
4000000
```

So `'3.71B'` -> `'3.71e9'` -> `3710000000L` etc.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an opportunity to **safely** use eval!! :-)

Consider the following fragment:

```
>>> d = { "B" :' * 1e9', "M" : '* 1e6'}
>>> s = "1.493B"
>>> ll = [d.get(c, c) for c in s]
>>> eval(''.join(ll), {}, {})
1493000000.0
```

Now put it all together into a neat one liner:

```
d = { "B" :' * 1e9', "M" : '* 1e6'}

def human_to_int(s):
    return eval(''.join([d.get(c, c) for c in s]), {}, {})

print human_to_int('1.439B')
print human_to_int('1.23456789M')
```

Gives back:

```
1439000000.0
1234567.89
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is safer and doesn't require ugly dictionaries passed as `eval` namespace

Comment: @jamylak `ast.literal_eval` only works for literals and not expressions - hence cannot be substituted in the above code. :)

Comment: Oh sorry I missed the `'* '` in the strings. I can't see properly today. On that note, If you remove the `' *'` then `ast.literal_eval` will work, although in that case you just use `int` and be more explicit and that solution has already been posted.

Comment: True .. but my solution is fully functional, while the int solution requires `if` statement :-)

Comment: Ah ok then +1 then, although you should remove the `'* 1'` and use `ast.literal_eval`.