# Converting string amount to integer amounts in python

Tags: python, arrays, regex, string

So I have the following string array :

```
amount = ['60 million', '1 million', '', '1.15 million', '1 million', 
'','2.48 million', '', '', '75 million', '1.25 million', '3 million',    
'67,000', '4 million', '', '63 million', '5.9 million', '170,000', '5
million', '22 million', '15.75 million', '36.5 million', '', '', '', '19.9 
million', '1.4 billion']
```

I would like to convert this into integer amounts so I can use it for a database... I'm having trouble on figuring out whats the best approach...for instance, I have mixed amounts of millions, billions, and thousands...
So the goal is to get the following integer array:

```
amount = [60000000, 1000000, 1150000....etc]
```

Comment: Looks like a great exercise ! What did you already try ?

Comment: Hey, why don't you get started and post your code (an [mcve])?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How can I consistently convert strings like “3.71B” and “4M” to numbers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11896560/2823755).

Comment: BTW: These arrays are called [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) in python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I consistently convert strings like "3.71B" and "4M" to numbers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896560/how-can-i-consistently-convert-strings-like-3-71b-and-4m-to-numbers-in-pytho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ints = []
for x in amount:
    if 'million' in x:
        ints.append(int(float(x.split()[0]) * 10**6))
    elif ',' in x:
        ints.append(int(x.replace(',','')))
    else:
        ints.append(0)
```

Output:

```
[60000000, 1000000, 0, 1150000, 1000000, 0, 2480000, 0, 0, 75000000, 1250000, 3000000, 67000, 4000000, 0, 63000000, 5900000, 170000, 5000000, 22000000, 15750000, 36500000, 0, 0, 0, 19900000, 0]
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/LtZ6YF)

Comment: I was trying to understand this: re.match(r'[^ ]+', x).group())

Comment: @Sammy7 It means match (`re.match`) from start of the string any char that is not space `[^ ]` one and unlimited times `+`. Don't use `re` (regex) it is way slower. [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j8sxnw/1) P.S. I updated my post using split and replace.

Comment: Many thanks for that !! I just started learning regex and its very confusing....

Answer (score 0):

You can define a dictionary of unit

```
unit = { "million" = 1000000,
         "thousands" = 1000,
        ...
       }
```

Then you can split amount list with space and apply multiplication from unit dict based on what unit you have in the split.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking of something along these lines...so

Comment: Ok, I was thinking of something along these lines...so if tried something like if string.contains (millions) , then replace millions with ' ', and trim all empty space, convert to integer, and then multiply by 1000000. And can repeat that with billion as well. And for the thousands, I just need to remove the commas. Cool !

Comment: @Sammy7 Hints: `replace()`, `split()`, `float()`, `lower()`, `append()`.