# Converting a string object value with M and K to million and thousand

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on a python/jupyter notebook exercise. The problem with my column values has `'K'` for thousand and `'M'` for Millions.

Need help on how to do the following:

1. How do I make the values with 'K' thousand values
2. How do I make the values with 'M' million values (both for whole number and with decimal)

note: I'm currently using jupyter notebook with pandas and numpy import

I want the output to be like:

450K to 450000
9.5M to 9500000
12M to 12000000

here is the link for the datafile column under 'Value'

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BOUVYiY6iRLbUdimCg7rgwtecfU6QAwS

See attached file:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  It is preferable to place data as text in your question so solvers experiment with it (they can't use the image as well).

Comment: Do you want to multiply by 1000 or 1000000 or replace k with thousand and m with million?

Comment: Yes, specify how you want your output to be.

Comment: i want the output to be like:

450K to 450000
9.5M to 9500000
12M to 12000000

Comment: @DCDSD my answer gives both in that case

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert to numbers--Adapted from this post--[How can I consistently convert strings like "3.71B" and "4M" to numbers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896560/how-can-i-consistently-convert-strings-like-3-71b-and-4m-to-numbers-in-pytho)

```
import numpy as np

def text_to_num(text, bad_data_val = 0):
    d = {
        'K': 1000,
        'M': 1000000,
        'B': 1000000000
    }
    if not isinstance(text, str):
        # Non-strings are bad are missing data in poster's submission
        return bad_data_val

    elif text[-1] in d:
        # separate out the K, M, or B
        num, magnitude = text[:-1], text[-1]
        return int(float(num) * d[magnitude])
    else:
        return float(text)
```

**Processing Poster's FIFA Dataset**

The stats vary depending upon what we set as the default for the bad or missing data.

This is more evident when we process the *Wage* column which has a lot more missing data than the *Value* column.

**Example**

```
print("Starting Values\n", df['Wage'].head())
for default_val in [0, None]:  # Try 0 and None for missing data fields
    print('\nUsing Default Value {}'.format(default_val))
    df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda row: text_to_num(row['Wage'], default_val), axis=1)
    print("Converted values:\n", df['Result'].head())
    print("\nStats {}".format(default_val))
    print(df['Result'].dropna().describe())  # Get stats dropping missing data (i.e. None values)
    print('-'*20)
```

**Output**

Note:

(1) When 0 is used as the default value, it brings down the stats (i.e. min of zero and lower mean)

(2) When None is used as defaultValue we ignore the value and have better stats

```
Starting Values
 0    565K
1    565K
2    280K
3    510K
4    230K
Name: Wage, dtype: object

Using Default Value 0
Converted values:
 0    565000
1    565000
2    280000
3    510000
4    230000
Name: Result, dtype: int64

Stats 0
count     17981.000000
mean      11546.966242
std       23080.000139
min           0.000000
25%        2000.000000
50%        4000.000000
75%       12000.000000
max      565000.000000
Name: Result, dtype: float64
--------------------

Using Default Value None
Converted values:
 0    565000.0
1    565000.0
2    280000.0
3    510000.0
4    230000.0
Name: Result, dtype: float64

Stats None
count     17733.000000
mean      11708.453166
std       23200.122784
min        1000.000000
25%        2000.000000
50%        4000.000000
75%       12000.000000
max      565000.000000
Name: Result, dtype: float64
--------------------
```

Comment: the numbers are part of the data frame. how do I extract it first so I can use your approach?

Comment: @dcdsd--Are the numbers in a Numpy array or Dataframe?  If you have a numpy array say a, then b = np.array(list(map(text_to_num, a) would give your new numpy array. If they are in a Pandas dataframe then you could use apply (which I can show if you're not familiar with it).

Comment: it comes in the dataframe imported from excel. not to familiar with apply yet (as I'm just beginner level) but it would be good if you can show me.

Comment: @DCDSD--updated my answer so you see how it could be applied.

Comment: @DarryIG  -- here is the error; I think the other problem is the decimal point, not all values are whole number
      1 c = data.Value.unique()
----> 2 result = np.array(list(map(text_to_num, c)))

<ipython-input-148-bb1eb212c586> in text_to_num(text, conversion)
      8         'B': 9
      9     }
---> 10     if text[-1] in d:
     11         # separate out the K, M, or B
     12         num, magnitude = text[:-1], text[-1]

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @DCDSD--you may double-check that you're using my latest version.  My example shows I'm testing on the first 8 values of your data which includes numbers with and without decimal points and it works for that.

Comment: @DCDSD--was able to process your data (see my updated post with new code).  The problem was there is a value towards the last row in the Value column which is not a string.  Simple fix --just checked if the value is a string.

Comment: oh yeah! now i notice that! How do i get rid of those values?

€ 0.00

Comment: @DCDSD--provided another update that returns 0 for non-strings.  So with  df['Wage'] = df.apply(lambda row: text_to_num(row['Wage']), axis=1) will replace the € 0.00 with zero (and also K with numbers).

Comment: @DCDSD--provided another update that allows you to specify a default for bad values.  Showed the result of using 0 vs None as the default.

Answer (score 0):

This answer converts a list named `y` to a list named `numbers`, replacing K with Thousand, and M with Million, and a list named `strings` which multiplies the number before k with 1000 and the number before m with 1000000.

```
y = data.Value.unique()

strings = []
numbers = []

for number in y:
    if number[-1:] == 'K':  # Check if the last digit is K
        strings.append(number[:-1] + " Thousand")  # Append a Thousand after removing the last char
        numbers.append(float(number[:-1]) * 1000)  # Remove the last digit with [:-1], and convert to int and multiply by 1000
    elif number[-1:] == 'M':  # Check if the last digit is M
        strings.append(number[:-1] + " Million")  # Append a Million after removing the last char
        numbers.append(float(number[:-1]) * 1000000)  # Remove the last digit with [:-1], and convert to int and multiply by 1000000
    else:  # just in case data doesnt have an M or K
        strings.append(number)
        numbers.append(int(number))
```

use 
`print(numbers)`
to print the numeric values of the numbers

Comment: the numbers are part of the data frame. how do I extract it first so I can use your approach?

Comment: do you mean the list of numbers?

Comment: yes. the list of numbers is part of the dataframe. as shown on the image

Comment: run `c = data.Value.unique()`, before my code. I have edited my code to match that

Comment: `for number in y:` should be replaces with `for number in c:` right?

Comment: It gives this error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-136-a08d89c10dfb> in <module>

      4 numbers = []

      5 

----> 6 for number in y:

      7     if number[:-1] == 'K':  # Check if the last digit is K

      8         strings.append(number[:-1] + " Thousand")  # Append a Thousand after removing the last char


NameError: name 'y' is not defined

Comment: oops yea thats what i meant

Comment: @DCDSD im sorry try the new code  i accidentally set the variable to y

Comment: cool! I have change it already. now giving me this error:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-141-4a7cf7d4d0fa> in <module>
     13     else:  # just in case data doesnt have an M or K
     14         strings.append(number)
---> 15         numbers.append(int(number))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '95.5M'

Comment: i think another problem is not just the K and M, also some of the values has decimal point.

Comment: Omg such a silly mistake I think this code should work for sure! Sorry man @DCDSD

Comment: That wont be an issue it was just me being lazy and not pre testing code

Comment: Tell me if it works hopefully this will be the accepted answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204975/discussion-between-dcdsd-and-sanjit-sarda).